# Switch to Desktop N with multiple displays

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to be able to move between spaces on MacOS Mojave on one display, switch to another display, and then move between spaces there, all using the keyboard (no mouse!). I've tried using MacOS's built in **Switch to Desktop N** option in System Preferences to switch between desktops on multiple displays – Desktop 1 on display 1 and Desktop 2 on display 2 – but focus won't move between the displays when invoking the command, so I can't switch spaces thereafter on the correct display.

System Preferences:
[image]

Desktop 1:
[image]

Desktop 2:
[image]

Having both Desktop 1 and Desktop 2 on the same display works fine, so I'm wondering if there's some other preference I've forgotten to enable to make this work on multiple displays. I've read a couple of answers here on SO suggesting third party applications to make this work, but most of them are from a couple of years back, and I'm hoping this would work natively on MacOS as of now.

Comment: Basically, if you have 'displays have separate spaces' enabled, the one that will change is the one with the cursor in it. There's no way round that.

Comment: Also I noticed as I inlined the images - Spaces needs more 'desktops' than physical monitors to work properly, if you're going to do the 'separate spaces' version. Fullscreens don't count [in fact fullscreen is an absolute hinderance to what you're trying to do]

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Welcome - have a look at this for some ideas, perhaps - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179376/what-is-an-efficient-way-for-developers-power-users-to-use-osx-window-manageme